# Groovy Actor Behaving Strange

Tags: grails, groovy, gpars

I have this piece of code:

```
class GitDownloader extends DefaultActor {

    private String dir

    @Override
    protected void act() {
        loop {
            react {
                repos -> if (repos instanceof String[])
                    println "Total Repos: ${repos.size()}"
                    repos.each {
                        repo ->
                            "git clone ssh://git@bar-src.foo.com/${repo} ${dir}/${repo.split("/").last()}".execute()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I start it like this:

```
def gitDownloader = new GitDownloader(dir: sourceCodeFolder)
gitDownloader.start()
gitDownloader << repositories
```

The problem is that the task executes in random order.
It should run the `git clone` command as many times as the repos.size() is but it does not. It runs a random number of times everytime.

That `each` loop should be executed in the background as a single task, it seems that the `git clone` commands are executed in parallel.

Comment: Why a `String[]`?  Also, you only have the `println` inside the `if` statement...  Is this your intention?

Comment: what am I supposed to pass? I have a list of repos I want to download. Ignore the println statement

Answer (score 2):

If you're sending a List, it will be a List that is received...

The following code:

```
import groovyx.gpars.actor.*

class GitDownloader extends DefaultActor {

    private String dir

    @Override
    protected void act() {
        loop {
            react { repos -> 
                println "Got an ${repos.getClass()} of repos"
                repos.each {
                    repo ->
                        println "doing $repo for dir $dir"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def g = new GitDownloader(dir:'woo')
g.start()
g << ['a', 'b']
```

prints:

```
Got an class java.util.ArrayList of repos
doing a for dir woo
doing b for dir woo
```

Which seems to work as expected...

Or changing it to do one at a time (added a sleep to simulate some work being done)

```
import groovyx.gpars.actor.*

class GitDownloader extends DefaultActor {

    private String dir

    @Override
    protected void act() {
        loop {
            react { repo -> 
                println "Got an ${repo.getClass()} of repos"
                println "doing $repo for dir $dir"
                Thread.sleep(1000)
            }
        }
    }
}

def g = new GitDownloader(dir:'woo')
g.start()
g << 'a' << 'b'
g
```

Also works, and prints:

```
Got an class java.lang.String of repos
doing a for dir woo
Got an class java.lang.String of repos
doing b for dir woo
```

From your code, I can't see the issue (apart from the `String[]` thing)